# find non-existant alphabetic letters in string

Tags: java

This is my code and I need it to return all letters that the user has not entered from the alphabet. For example, if the input is "abcd" the output in result should be the rest of the alphabet. It'd be really nice if someone could help. Right now the output of my code is the whole alphabet no matter what input is given. I tried getting the same letters to be output using "==" instead of "!=" and that worked. So I really don't understand why the opposite won't work.

```
    String s;
    System.out.println("input string:");
    s = sc.nextLine();

    
     char c;
     String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
     Set<String> str = new HashSet<String>();
     for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
         c = s.charAt(i);
        if( (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
            for(int j=0; j<alphabet.length(); j++){
                if(c!=alphabet.charAt(j)) {
                    str.add(alphabet.charAt(j)+"");
                }
                }
            }
    }  

    System.out.println("result:");
    System.out.println(str);
    sc.close();

}
```

Comment: `c` is one of the `alphabet` value, `c!=a` is `true`. just check once whether `c` is in `alphabet ` using `contains`, and `a` and `A` are different so adjust your logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contains method is appropriate in this case:

```
 String s;
System.out.println("input string:");
s = sc.nextLine();

 String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 Set<String> str = new HashSet<String>();
   
    for(int j=0; j<alphabet.length(); j++){
            if(!s.contains(alphabet.charAt(j)+"")){
                str.add(alphabet.charAt(j)+"");
            }
        
    } 

System.out.println("result:");
System.out.println(str);
sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner for-if actually says "for each input character c, output whole alphabet except c and union all results", which produces whole alphabet for any input of two distinct characters.

Initialize `str` set with all characters of alphabet and then remove each character from input. LinkedHashSet is important to preserve order (thanks to ControlAltDel).

```java
    static List<String> listByChar(String s) {
        return s.chars().mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf((char)i)).collect(toList());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        Set<String> str = new LinkedHashSet<>(listByChar(alphabet));
        str.removeAll(listByChar(s));
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

What remains in `str` is result you want.

Comment: Have you tested this? I'd have thought that adding all the characters to a HashSet would scramble them. Then you have a job to re-order them. Can you test and confirm that you can get the HashSet back to an in order alphabetic string? I'll remove my down vote if I'm wrong here :)

Comment: @ControlAltDel you are right of course, I was hot-headed, sorry :-). Now it is fixed. Thanks for point, I deserved downvote. I also appreciate you didn't vote anonymously and explained the reason.

Comment: np Tomas. I am not here to punish. I'm here to make sure you GET IT RIGHT :)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use regular expressions (I don't know if you are allowed to do this)

Here's how to write it:

```
String s;
System.out.println("input string:");
s = sc.nextLine();

//then turn those letters into a regex character capture group
s = "[" + s + "]";
//then run the regular expression
String ans = alphabet.replaceAll(s,"");
```

If you're not allowed to use Regex, please update your question, and I'll delete this answer okay?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```

It would be better to add this code.